# Discrete mathematics Sets Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Guys can you help me solve whether these relations are reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric or transitive please ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkAuN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is an exercise in using definitions. For example, consider symmetry. What does it mean for a relation to be symmetric? If $R$ Is a relation on a set $A$, you are saying for all elements $a$ and $b$ in $A$, if $(a, b)$ is an element of $R$, then $(b, a)$ must be an element of $R$. If the relation meets this requirement for all $(a, b)$ in $R$, it is symmetric. If it does not, then it is not. You should look carefully at each definition and examine each of your sets to see if it meets that criteria. Using definitions is a very important concept in mathematics, so don't just ask for the answer. Do your best on the problem, post your results, and ask for feedback, many people will be more than happy to help if they see you are trying.